# How do I know how many rows of data I have when working with a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Sometimes, I deal with data that has over 1000 rows and do not want to scroll for a long time in order to copy data that I created through a formula

It took too long for me to copy the formula to the rest of the cells in the column that I was working with

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to copy that much data at once, instead of holding down your mouse to select you can do this instead.

Select the top left corner of the data, then using the scroll bar, scroll all the way down to the bottom right of the data. Then hit `CTRL + SHIFT` to select everything in-between. Then you can copy your data then.

If this isn't what you're talking about, are you able to explain in detail what your issue is?